# How to view images in built-in imageviewer on android

Tags: android

i am work in a view images in my app. i want to view the images from drawable folder to built-in image viewer in a android device.how to i open images from project resource on built-in image viewer can help with any code or tutorial greatly appreciated!

i want to view image like screen shot:

[image]

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the code..

phonebookImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.backphonebook);

Thanks.

Comment: you don't understand my question,i want to show images for built-in image viewer like your device view image from gallery not a view image to imageview!

Comment: Hi, create a Integer Array from your drawable folder and use this array show image from drawable....

Comment: but,i want to view images in built-in viewer because,view images with zoom in,zoom out,slide to next image functionality!

Answer (score 0):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

            String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" +R.drawable.yourimagename;  

 // path = "/mnt/sdcard/test.jpg";

            //Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));

             Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

            intent.setDataAndType(uri,"image/*");
            context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i am getting error my logcat shows the message:06-25 17:33:13.494: E/AndroidRuntime(7491): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.animation/com.animation.AnimationActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=android.resource://com.animation/2130837504 typ=image/* }

Comment: public String getRawPath(int yourimageId) {
return "android.resource//" + getPackageName() + "/raw/" + yourimageId;
}